# Linear Dependence Lemma

Tags: linear-algebra

This is out of my textbook, Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right" which I am self-studying from. (*I organized my thoughts in which I would like some sort of response with Roman Numerals*).

**Linear Dependence Lemma**: If $(v_{1},\ldots,v_{m})$ is linearly dependent in $V$ and $v_{1} \neq 0$, then there exists $j \in \{2,\ldots,m\}$ such that the following hold:

(a) $v_{j} \in span(v_{1},\ldots,v_{j-1})$;

*(**I.** Why does this need to be justified? Is it because $v_{j}$ is an "extra" vector, which would make this arbitrary set of linear combinations dependent?).*

(b) If the $j^{th}$ term is removed from $(v_{1},\ldots,v_{m})$, the span of the remaining list equal $span(v_{1},\ldots,v_{m})$.

*(**II.** My assumption is that this basically means that if we remove this extra vector, then we still have the same list of linear combinations).*

*(I also found the following proof a bit confusing and need some clarification).*

PROOF: Suppose $(v_{1},\ldots,v_{m})$ is linearly dependent in $V$ and $v_{1} \neq 0$. Then there exists $a_{1},\ldots,a_{m} \in \mathbb{F}$, not all $0$ such that $$a_{1}v_{1}+\cdots+a_{m}v_{m} = 0$$.

(So far so good, from what I know, this is just stating the opposite of Linear Independence, where the only choice of $a_{1},\ldots,a_{m} \in \mathbb{F}$ that satisfies $a_{1}v_{1}+\cdots+a_{m}v_{m} = 0$  is $a_1 =\cdots= a_{m} = 0$)

CONT: Not all of $a_{2},a_{3},\ldots,a_{m}$ can be $0$ (because $v_1 \neq 0)$. Let $j$ be the largest element of $\{2,\ldots.,m\}$ such that $a_{j} \neq 0$. Then  $$ v_{j} = -\frac{a_1}{a_j}v_1 - \cdots - \frac{a_{j-1}}{a_j}v_{j-1} ,$$

proving (a).

*(**III.** I will fill in the extra steps here because I feel that I may have the right idea).*

$Span(v_{1},\ldots,v_{m}) = 0$ for $j \in \{2,\ldots,m\} = a_{1}v_{1} + \cdots + a_{j}v_{j} = 0$.

Here I just solved for $v_j$, and got the result  $v_{j} = -\frac{a_1}{a_j}v_1 - \cdots - \frac{a_{j-1}}{a_j}v_{j-1} ,$ which corresponds to the above. $a_{j} \neq 0$ because we have $a_j^{-1}$ for each term, and $v_1 \neq 0$ because if we have $a_{1}v_{1}+\cdots+a_{j}v_{j} = 0$ then all the scalars $a_{2},\ldots,a_{m} \in \mathbb{F}$ could be equal to $0$, if that was the case. I think I have an idea, but how exactly does this prove that $v_j$ is contained in the span of $(v_{1},\ldots,v_{j-1})$? Is it because $ -\frac{a_1}{a_j}v_1 - \cdots - \frac{a_{j-1}}{a_j}v_{j-1}$, is just a linear combination of vectors that is equal to $v_j$?

CONT: to prove (b), suppose that $u \in span(v_{1},\ldots,v_{m})$. Then there exists $c_{1},\ldots,c_m \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $$u = c_1v_1 + \cdots + c_mv_m$$.

In the equation above, we replace $v_j$ with the right side of 2.5, which shows that $u$ is in the span of the list obtained by removing the $j^{th}$ term from $(v_1,\ldots,v_m)$. Thus (b) holds. $\Box$

(**IV.** So how exactly does this work? I find this part the most confusing).

Sorry that this is such a long list, but I really want to fully understand everything I am learning, and I am pretty new to proving stuff, so I want to make sure that I improve that skill as well.

Comment: for part 3 involving the linear dependence proof. Since $\frac{-a_i}{a_j}$ are all nonzero scalars in $F$ where $1\leq i \leq j-1$ then $v_j$ is a linear combination of those nonzero terms

Comment: Alright cool, that's what I was thinking. Thanks for that added clarification.

Comment: Did you make a mistake here : "Linear Dependence Lemma: If (v1,...,vm) is linearly independent in V and v1≠0, then there exists j∈{2,...,m} such that the following hold" ?

Comment: I believe I did. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: For a question about the (unnecessary) condition $v_1\neq0$, see [What's special about the first vector?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/426246/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I. Why does (a) need to be justified

Because every claim made needs to be. The essence of (a) is that if there is a linear dependence, then there is a specific index $j$ such that the blame of linear dependence can be given to $v_j$, for its failing to be independent of its predecessors. A different way to prove this is to consider the list of sequences $()$, $(v_1)$, $(v_1,v_2)$, $\ldots$, $(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_m)$; since the first one is linearly independent and the last one is linearly dependent (by assumption) there must be a first one in the list the is linearly dependent; if this is $(v_1,\ldots,v_j)$ then one can show $v_j\in span(v_1,\ldots,v_{-1})$. The argument is similar to the proof given in the text (a linear dependence relation among $(v_1,\ldots,v_j)$ must involve $v_j$ with nonzero coefficient). An advantage of this approach is that it does not depend essentially on any choice (the linear dependency taken is unique up to a scalar multiple) and it puts the blame on the very first $v_j$ that causes linear dependence.

> II. My assumption is that (b) basically means that if we remove this extra vector, then we still have the same list of linear combinations.

More precisely, the removal of $v_j$ does not affect the *set of vectors* that can be written as linear combinations, even though the linear combinations themselves look different (since $v_j$ is no longer allowed to appear).

> III. I will fill in... $span(v_{1},\ldots,v_{m}) = 0$ for $j \in \{2,\ldots,m\} = a_{1}v_{1} + \cdots + a_{j}v_{j} = 0$.
>   Here I just solved for $v_j$, and got the result  $v_j = -\frac{a_1}{a_j}v_1 - \cdots - \frac{a_{j-1}}{a_j}v_{j-1} ,$ which corresponds to the above. $a_{j} \neq 0$ because we have $a_j^{-1}$ for each term,

You've got that a bit backwards. You could only solve for $v_j$ under the assumption $a_j\neq0$; you cannot conclude that from the fact that you just solved for $v_j$.

> and $v_1 \neq 0$ because if we have $a_{1}v_{1}+\cdots+a_{j}v_{j} = 0$ then all the scalars $a_{2},\ldots,a_{m} \in \mathbb{F}$ could be equal to $0$, if that was the case.

This is doubly beside the point. $v_1\neq0$ is given, you don't need to prove that. On the other hand there is nothing absurd in the scalars $a_{2},\ldots,a_{m} \in \mathbb{F}$ all being equal to $0$, except that the text had just proved it is not the case *using* the fact that $v_1\neq0$. But the author could have avoided the whole mess about $v_1$ by observing that $span()=\{0\}$.

> I think I have an idea, but how exactly does this prove that $v_j$ is contained in the span of $(v_{1},\ldots,v_{j-1})$? Is it because $ -\frac{a_1}{a_j}v_1 - \cdots - \frac{a_{j-1}}{a_j}v_{j-1}$, is just a linear combination of vectors that is equal to $v_j$?

Precisely.

> In the equation above, we replace $v_j$ with the right side of 2.5, which shows that $u$ is in the span of the list obtained by removing the $j^{th}$ term from $(v_1,\ldots,v_m)$. Thus (b) holds. $\Box$
>
> IV. So how exactly does this work?

If you write down a linear combination of $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ it contains a single occurrence of $v_j$. If you replace that occurrence (within parentheses, as it gets multiplied by a scalar) by the right hand side of 2.5, then there is no longer any occurrence of $v_j$. You don't directly get a linear combination of the remaining $v_i$, but once you work out the multiplication and collect like terms, you do get such a linear combination. For instance if $v_3=-5v_1+\frac32v_2$ then
$$\begin{align}
  av_1+bv_2+cv_3+dv_4
&= av_1+bv_2+c(-5v_1+\frac32v_2)+dv_4
\\&= av_1+bv_2-5cv_1+\frac32cv_2+dv_4
\\&= (a-5c)v_1+(b+\frac32c)v_2+dv_4.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Awesome answer!

Comment: Why is it that noting $span\{\} = {0}$ is important to justify that $v_1$ can also be zero? Does this include the case where our set of vectors is the null space? I'm not sure I understand that part fully.

Comment: I'm just saying that the whole exception that is made in the statement of the lemma for $j=1$ is unnecessary: if the conclusion had included $j=1$ then one could drop the condition $v_1\neq0$ of the lemma; then the lemma and the proof would have been simplified. Indeed it could happen that we need to take $j=1$ in the conclusion precisely because $v_1$ happens to be $0$; this is OK since $0\in span()$. [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/426246/) discusses that aspect in detail.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: If $j = 1$, how would $v_j \in span(v_1,\ldots,v_{j-1})$ get rewritten?

Comment: @StVincent As $v_j\in span()$, which implies $v_j=0$. If you mean how $v_j$ is written as linear combination of no vectors at all, the answer is that the [only such linear combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum#An_example:_empty_linear_combinations) is the empty sum, whose value is the zero vector.

Comment: I mean more generally, since if $j = 0$ then we get $v_1 \in span(v_1,v_0)$

Comment: No, the notation $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ denotes the empty sequence when $n=0$, not the sequence $v_1,v_0$. This convention is the standard interpretation of notation using three dots, it applies very generally. Just like $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ is an empty sum when $n=0$.

Comment: Oh, I see. So by definition if $j = 1$, then $span(v_1,\ldots,v_{j-1}) = span\{\}$, which is just a linear combination of $0$ terms.

Comment: Also, if $j = 2$, then would it be written as $v_2 \in span(v_1)$? I get a bit confused because $v_1$ is already listed in the span, but we have the $v_{2-1}$ which lists the vector twice. Thanks for all your patience, I feel like I am very close to fully understanding this Lemma.