# Let $S =\{u_1, u_2,...,u_n\}$ be a finite set of vectors. Prove that $S$ is linearly dependent iff $u_1 = 0$ or $u_{k+1} ∈ span(\{u_1, u_2,...,u_k\})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, fake-proofs

Let $S =\{u_1, u_2,...,u_n\}$ be a finite set of vectors. Prove that $S$ is linearly dependent if and only if $u_1 = 0$ or $u_{k+1} ∈ \text{span} (\{u_1, u_2,...,u_k\})$ for some $k\space (1 ≤ k<n).$

I solved the problem as follows:
If $u_1=0$ then $S$ is linearly independent as $1.0=1.u_1=0.$

If $u_{k+1} ∈ \text{span} (\{u_1, u_2,...,u_k\})$ then, $\exists$ scalars $c_1,...,c_k$ such that $$u_{k+1}=c_1u_1+...+c_ku_k\implies u_{k+1}-c_1u_1-...-c_ku_k=0,$$ which means $S$ is linearly dependent.

Now, for the other part we assume that  $S$ is linearly dependent. If $u_1=0\in S$ then we are done. Else, from the definition of linear dependent sets we can find a finite set of vectors $a_1,...,a_{k+1}$ and scalars $c_1,...,c_{k+1}$ not all zero, such that $c_1a_1+...+c_{k+1}a_{k+1}=0$. Assuming $c_{k+1}\neq 0$  we have, $$a_{k+1}=c_{k+1}^{-1}c_1a_1+c_{k+1}^{-1}c_2a_2+...+c_{k+1}c_ka_k\implies a_{k+1}\in\text{span} (\{a_1, a_2,...,a_k\}).$$ Let $u1=a_1,u_2=a_2,...,u_k=a_k,u_{k+1}=a_{k+1}$ and then, we have, $u_{k+1} ∈ \text{span} (\{u_1, u_2,...,u_k\}).$

This completes the proof.

---

**I think the question is ambiguous** because if $u_{k+1} ∈ \text{span} (\{u_1, u_2,...,u_k\})$ is the claim (when $u_1\neq 0$), then they implicitly assume, that the coefficient of $u_1$ is always equal to $0$ if $u_1\neq 0.$ This is because, it was also a possible case, that $u_2$ was a linear combination of the vectors $$u_1,...,u_n(\implies u_2\in \text{span}(\{u_1,u_3,...,u_n\}))$$ and in addition, we have $u_2\notin \text{span}(\{u_1\}).$ Then the claim in the question would've been incorrect. The question is thus, wrong if we examine it carefully. *Am i correct?*

Comment: You haven't given an example where the claim in the question is incorrect; you've given an example where the claim is not satisfied by $k=2$ (but some $k>2$ will still work).

Comment: There is no dilemma, no ambiguity. The proposition in the first two lines is true. Your proof seems to me defective since the "assume $c_{k+1}\ne 0$" is not explained. You need to be more precise in the way you pick $k$

Comment: Yes, if you are asked to "prove" something, then it "needs some rigorous proof". The claim that you are being asked to show is not *obvious*; it is nevertheless true. (Your proof, however, is indeed not sufficient to conclude the stronger claim.)

Comment: You may not re-order the given $u_1, u_2,\dots, u_n$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linear Dependence Lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492989/linear-dependence-lemma)

Comment: I cannot understand many of your questions  - the bold ones. To prove the proposition surely all one needs do is note that there are scalars $a_i$, not all $0$, such that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i u_i=0$; now choose the largest $k$ such that $a_{k+1}\ne 0$.

Comment: It does not need to be *strictly* between those; it could be $(v_1, v_2, \dots, v_m)$ itself, which is linearly dependent by assumption.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I posted an answer below. I'll be glad if you review whether I got the thing or not? I think my answer sums up the subtle point rather than that answer you linked.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I posted an answer. I'll be grateful if you consider taking a look at it. I think that is what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really overthinking this. This answer is inspired from the comment of the user ancient mathematician.

Your first part which shows that if $u_1=0$ or if for some $k\in [1,n)$ such that $u_{k+1}\in\text{span}(\{u_1,u_2,...,u_{k-1}\})$ then $S$ is linearly dependent is correct. Also all's perfect upto the point where you showed, if $S$ is linearly dependent and $u_1=0$ then we are done.

The problem arises with the way you tried to prove, the statement:

*If $S=\{u_1,u_2,...,u_n\}$ is a linearly dependent set then $\exists k$  satisfying $1\leq k\lt n$ such that, $u_{k+1}\in\text{span}(\{u_1,u_2,...,u_{k-1}\}).$*

We give a proof of this (above) mentioned statement below:

Given $S=\{u_1,u_2,...,u_n\}.$ Since, $S$ is linearly dependent, there exist scalars $a_1,...,a_n$ not all zero such that $$a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_nu_n=\sum_{i=1}^na_iu_i=0.$$ We choose the largest $1\leq k\lt n$ such that $a_{k+1}\neq 0.$ Then, $a_{k+1}u_{k+1}=a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_{k}u_{k}+a_{k+2}u_{k+2}+...+a_nu_n\implies a_{k+2}=a_{k+3}=\cdots=a_n=0$ as $k$ is the largest of all the integers such that $a_{k+1}\neq 0.$ So, $$a_{k+1}u_{k+1}=a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_{k}u_{k}+a_{k+2}u_{k+2}+...+a_nu_n=a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_{k}u_{k}+0.u_{k+2}+\cdots +0.a_n=a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_{k-1}u_{k-1}\implies u_{k+1}=a_{k+1}^{-1}a_1u_1+...+a_{k+1}^{-1}a_{k-1}u_{k-1}\implies u_{k+1}\in\text{span}(\{u_1,u_2,...,u_{k-1}\}).$$

---

This is all to it! With this modification, the proof in the original post should be fixed.

Comment: Seems good to me.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, I believe the cleanest and most efficient approach is to take the largest $k$ with $1\le k<n$ such that $\{u_1,\dots,u_k\}$ is linearly *independent*. (Note that we're using the hypothesis that $u_1\ne 0$ here.) This means that $\{u_1,\dots,u_k,u_{k+1}\}$ is linearly *dependent* and you can check immediately that $u_{k+1}\in\text{Span}(u_1,\dots,u_k)$.

Comment: You are right. My own hint was intended to go along with the OP's solution as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** The Claim at hand is totally Correct & unambiguous.

**(2A)** I am not sure why & how you state that the textbook Proof assumes that the co-efficient of $u_1$ must be $0$.
**(2B)** You also state that $u_2$ must be in the span of all other elements , which might be true but that is not related to the Claim at hand.

**(3)** The Claim at hand is about putting the elements in some order & then saying that there is at least 1 element $u_{k+1}$ which is in the span of the previous $k$ elements. It is not about whether some element $u_{k+1}$ is in the span of all other $(n-1)$ elements.
IMPORTANT : Here , the $u$ Element values are fixed , though the Order is not , because it is a Set.

**(4)** In other words , this might be easy to see like this :
Put the elements in order.
Either $1^{st}$ element is $0$
Or $2^{nd}$ element is in span of Previous element
Or $3^{rd}$ element is in span of Previous $2$ elements
Or $4^{th}$ element is in span of Previous $3$ elements
Or $5^{th}$ element is in span of Previous $4$ elements
Or $6^{th}$ element is in span of Previous $5$ elements
....
Or $n^{th}$ element is in span of Previous $(n-1)$ elements

Here , if all the Cases are not true , it means that we have linearly InDependent Elements.
If at least 1 Case had been true , it means that we have linearly Dependent Elements & that Case gives the least $k$ value.

*Important :* When the Order is changed , that $k$ value might change.

**(5)** There may or may not be other valid $k$ values , the Claim at hand is about getting at least 1 such $k$ value.
When we put the elements in some other Order , the $k$ value(s) might change.

This Example should clear things further ...

Let $S=\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1)\}$

I put in this order :
$u_1=(0,0)$
$u_2=(0,1)$
$u_3=(0,2)$ .... $u_n=(1,1)$
Then Claim is true : $u_1=0$

I put in this order :
$u_1=(0,1)$
$u_2=(0,2)$
$u_3=(1,1)$ .... $u_n=(0,0)$
Then Claim is true : $u_2=2u_1$

I put in this order :
$u_1=(0,1)$
$u_2=(1,0)$
$u_3=(1,1)$ .... $u_n=(0,0)$
Then Claim is true : $u_3=u_1+u_2$

Elements are fixed , Order is not fixed.
We choose 1 Order & then go with the Claim , to get the $k$ value according to that Order.

**Note:** When  we put in "Some Order" & get a $k$ value , then we have linearly Dependent Elements.

*If we put in "Some Other Order" , then we MUST get a $k$ value ( might or might not be Same $k$ value ) , other-wise we would have linearly Independent Elements !*

Comment: Ok, so we fix an ordering and prove the claim. But what I thought is, we prove that   some $k+1$ elements are linearly dependent and later label them as $u_i's$ to prove the claim (according to which I modified muly solution in OP).  *But how are being so sure that for a particular ordering such a claim is valid? I think this needs some rigorous proof.*

Comment: Wait, "If we put in "Some Other Order" , then we MUST get a k
 value ( might or might not be Same k
 value ) , other-wise we would have linearly InDependent Elements !" - **Why?**